# Movie about people trying to stop a dinosaur

Tags: story-identification, movie, dinosaurs

I forgot the name of the film, which involves a red light glowing dinosaur, or something similar to Godzilla.

In the story, people are trying to stop it and using earthwork to trap it with the equipment they have. The hero joins some people around there, then makes a sword to attack.

The thing comes at night. There is a scene where the hero throws a stick torch into a dark area where the creature was hiding, and then red light glows on its body.

Comment: Welcome asif. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for our guidelines, also take the time to read our [story ID checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if you can add a bit more helpful detail.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this? Did you see it on TV or online? And in which country and language did you watch it in?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 10):

[Outlander](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0462465), 2008.  It’s basically [Beowulf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf) with aliens and vikings.

The monster is called a [Moorwen](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Moorwen).

The [plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlander_(film)) contains a night scene where the Moorwen [lights up and shows itself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r07NtBvetHs).
Then there’s a sequence where they try to kill it by trapping it in a big pit filled with burning whale oil.  Later there is a montage where swords are made from scavenged fragments of starship hull.

Comment: Asked about again here:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/273667/movie-with-vikings-warriors-fighting-an-alien-that-looks-like-a-wolf-with-tentac