# Movie with vikings/warriors fighting an alien that looks like a wolf with tentacles

Tags: story-identification, movie

I don't quite remember the setting but it seemed to be medieval or viking-ish. These warriors are dealing with a single monster that as I remember was wolf-like with tentacles coming out of its back, translucent and the tips of the tendrils glowed red. The group of warriors are slowly being picked off and sort of have a final stand to try and fight it or better off, kill it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  Was it animated or live-action?

Comment: *The Thing* had a husky dog (very wolf-like) that grew tentacles out of its back.  And it had Norwegians fighting against it, but they were modern-day Norwegians, not Vikings.  Close on a few points though...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264137/movie-about-people-trying-to-stop-a-dinosaur/264141

Answer (score 10):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlander_(film)

> A spacecraft crashes in a lake in Vendel-era Scandinavia (550–790).
> The only surviving occupant – a humanoid alien – retrieves a distress
> beacon and a computer which explains that he is on Earth, a "seed"
> colony that his people have abandoned. The computer downloads the
> local Norse language and culture directly into his brain. The spaceman
> soon finds a recently destroyed village, where he is captured by
> Wulfric (Jack Huston), a warrior from another village.
>
> Wulfric takes him to the fortified village of King Hrothgar (John
> Hurt), father of Freya (Sophia Myles), who he hopes will marry future
> king Wulfric. Hrothgar is concerned that Gunnar (Ron Perlman),
> chieftain of the destroyed village, will assume it was Wulfric's
> doing, as Wulfric's father (Hrothgar's predecessor) had been killed by
> Gunnar. Wulfric interrogates the "outlander", who identifies himself
> as Kainan (Jim Caviezel), claiming he is from the north, and states
> that he is hunting a dragon. The village is attacked that night by an
> unseen creature, which kills several men. Kainan identifies it as a
> "Moorwen", a predatory creature which caused his ship to crash and now
> will hunt men and animals alike. When Kainan is taken with a hunting
> party to find the Moorwen, he kills a gigantic bear that had slain
> some of the hunters, proving himself to the others who begin treating
> him as a part of their tribe.
>
> Gunnar and his men attack the settlement, retreating, after both sides
> suffer casualties. They soon return, pursued by the Moorwen, and enter
> the safety of the village. Kainan devises a plan to build a huge pit
> just inside the village entrance, fill it with whale oil and leave
> wooden shields floating on the surface.
>
> Freya becomes increasingly attracted to Kainan. He explains to her the
> Moorwen's origin—Kainan's people invaded its land (planet),
> slaughtered it in the billions and built a colony there. This Moorwen,
> now the last of its kind, massacred everyone in the colony, including
> Kainan's wife and child. When his "ship" returned to the colony, the
> Moorwen snuck onboard and later caused the crash. After listening to
> Kainan's tale, Freya gives him a family sword, saying she was told
> that she would know what man to give it to.

Scene that you probably remember:

Comment: YESSS this is it, thank you so much.

Comment: This is a duplicate

Comment: @Blang please mark it as accepted then :)

Comment: ChatGPT:
Movie with vikings/warriors fighting an alien that looks like a wolf with tentacles?

The movie you are thinking of is likely "Outlander" (2008), directed by Howard McCain. The movie follows a humanoid alien warrior named Kainan (played by Jim Caviezel), who crashes on Earth during the time of the Vikings. Kainan soon finds himself fighting alongside the Vikings against a vicious and deadly creature known as the Moorwen, which looks like a giant wolf with tentacles.

Impressive? Hell YES!